# Can a attachShadow return a #document-fragment that isn't a #shadow-root?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

I'm not using a polyfill in Chrome, and in some cases I see that `this.shadowRoot` in my custom element is a `#document-fragment` and not a `#shadow-root`.

For example, here's some code inside my custom element, see what it says when I hover in the debugger:

[image]

I was expecting to see `#shadow-root`.

Is there an upgrade process whereby during some small amount of time, initially, the `#document-fragment` is not yet a `#shadow-root`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shadowRoot` property should always be of type `#document-fragment` / [DocumentFragment](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-documentfragment).

As per the [WHATWG DOM specs](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-shadowroot):

> interface ShadowRoot : DocumentFragment {
>
> readonly attribute ShadowRootMode mode;
> readonly attribute Element host;
>
> };

You should see `#shadow-root` only in the *Element* pane.

You should see `#document-fragment` in the *Sources* pane.

Comment: Ah okay. Is there any reason why we see one or the other in different panes? Is that just vendor detail?

Comment: #document-fragment is the common name for element of type 11. For #shadow-root it is not in the spec so we could say it's just vendor detail (aslo used in Firefox)

Comment: You're right, and after investigating some errors I had, it isn't related to my problem at all. Thanks!